# An unknown error has occurred. Error: 80020101.

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, html, javascript, vkontakte-api

Пытаюсь сделать вход в вконтакт в приложении WP7 через текст боксы и свою кнопку "Войти". Чтобы заполнить поля мыла и пароля использую

```
Auth.InvokeScript("eval", string.Format("document.getElementsByName('email')[0].value='{0}'", Login.Text));
Auth.InvokeScript("eval", string.Format("document.getElementsByName('pass')[0].value='{0}'", Pass.Password));
```

Потом пытаюсь нажать кнопку, которая имеет свойства

```
< input class="btn" type="submit" value="Войти" />
```

скриптом

```
Auth.InvokeScript("eval", "document.forms[0].sumbit();");
```

и тут вылетает ошибка

> "An unknown error has occurred. Error: 80020101.".

Гугл говорит, что такое бывает, если пытаешься использовать элемент, который ещё не догрузился в странице. Заполнение почты и пароля у меня срабатывает по изменению их тексбокса (то есть, новый символ сразу же забивается в поле, которое отображается на страничке входа вконтакте). Проблема явно в моем скрипте, потому что если сделать браузер видимым (по умолчанию его не видно), и нажать кнопку входа именно на страничке - то все нормально работает и заходит.
Только что пытался ещё таким образом нажать

```
Auth.InvokeScript("var btns=document.getElementsByTagName('submit');
for(i=0;i<btns.length;i++) {
    if(btns[i].value=='Войти'){btns[i].click();}}");
```

но всё-равно ошибка, но другая,

> An unknown error has occurred. Error: 80020006.

Прошу помощи)

Comment: Как решили? Вот сижу и тоже с этим долбаюсь. Разница только в том, что пишу для МордоКниги. (хотя для контакта потом тоже писать). З.Ы, перечитал еще раз вопрос: а у вас поля для emai-а и пароля заполняются? Потому как у меня нет... Ошибка вылетает еще там.

Comment: Прям мистика. Пришел с обеда - заработало. ооооо

Comment: @Olter: эх, все ошибки бы так...

Comment: Интересно... Походу, все дело было в том, что не выполнен был logout. Т.е. вместо страницы с логином просто грузилась страница пользователя, на которой не было таких полей и кнопок.  По крайней мере, это единственное объяснение, которое я могу дать. Сейчас проверил, без логаута при перемещении на страницу с регистрацией сразу идет редирект на страницу юзверя. Ммм, не люблю я социальные сети :)